# node.js Typescript project, key-value pair

Tags: node.js, typescript, websocket

So I try to create a value pair type and get the error message: "Cannot find name 'key'."
How does it work properly?

```
import * as websocket from "websocket";
      
let wsClientsList: {[key: string]: websocket.connection};    
        
for(key in wsClientsList){
//  ^^^ TS2304: Cannot find name 'key'.
    wsClientsList[key].sendUTF(message);
    console.log('send Message to: ', wsClientsList[key]);
            }
```

Comment: `wsClientList` is `undefined` - you've declared it but haven't assigned anything to it. Also, `key` is undeclared.

Comment: `for (let key in wsClientsList) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare a variable named `key` using `var`, `let` or `const`

```
for(let key in wsClientsList) {
  wsClientsList[key].sendUTF(message);
  console.log('send Message to: ', wsClientsList[key]);
}
```

You can use `const` in most cases in `for in` and `for of` loops, unlike in traditional `for` loops with increment.